# Firefox web proxy not being called

Tags: firefox, proxy

I created a generic handler (similar to a web page) **Handler1.ashx**.

When I browse to `http://localhost:50824/Handler1.ashx` the handler is called. So it *is* working.

But when I set Firefox's Settings to `Manual proxy configuration` (in Advanced-Network-(Connection)-Settings) with the proxy being: `localhost/Handler1.ashx`  Port `50824`  and then browse the web (e.g. `http://Microsoft.com`) I get an error `Server not found`.

Why is the handler not being called by Firefox?

EDIT

I tried using `localhost` only, and setting the handler as the default page. As before, browsing to localhost:50824 works. But Firefox doesn't call the page (and I get an `HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.` error).

Comment: Frist guess: That box expects a host name, and `localhost/Handler1.ashx` is not a valid host name.  Perhaps we can help with a little more info... Why do you expect your generic HTTP handler is going to work as a web proxy?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 a) Why is localhost any worse than any other ip address? (I tried 127.0.0.1 as well.) b) I _don't_ expect it to be a proxy. This is just the first step. (I actually did write some of that proxy code as well, but obviously I can't test that until it's being called.) I know it's not being called because a breakpoint I put there is not being hit. It _is_ hit when browsing `http://localhost:50824/Handler1.ashx` so I know the handler is "activated".

Comment: "Why is localhost any worse than any other ip address" I didn't say it was?  What I'm suggesting is that you're specifying the ASHX file name as well, which makes it no longer a valid host name. My thinking is that you would specify just the host name and a port, and then on that port, on that host, you answer with your handler (or whatever you want to use as a proxy) as the default.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I actually tried setting the handler as the default page for the application and simply used `localhost` with the port. It didn't work. (Since it didn't help - I didn't mention it. Assuming that I'm missing something else here.) And as before - browsing to `http://localhost:50824` does work. Firefox, on the other hand, never calls it.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 See edit for the error message (in Firefox) itself.

Comment: Weird. I'm assuming you're using IIS, correct?  Which version (for completeness' sake ;) ).  Can you edit your question and include the bindings you have set for the server (applicationhost.config) and the site in question?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 IIS (as far as I know - iisexpress), Windows 10 Pro, x64, Visual Studio 2015, Web application project - Default empty Web Forms project + the handler + defaultDocument in web.config, there is no applicationhost.config in the project, and the site is localhost (- it's not public facing. It's just my computer.)